# Nginx Proxy Pass 404 on CSS and JS Resources

Tags: javascript, css, nginx, http-status-code-404, proxypass

Trying to host a website with Nginx and redirect traffic for a path to a local NodeJS service on port 3000)

**Issue**: Some CSS and JS resources are 404 Not Found.

Nginx Setup (HTTPS managed by certbot configurations abbreviated)

```
server {
  
  root /var/www/example.com;
  index index.html;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
  
  location /control/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
```

However, there are CSS and JS resources with 404 Not Found, preventing the website from properly loading. Example:

```
GET https://example.com/css/chunk-vendors.42e53ce6.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://example.com/js/app.4f600198.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

However, these resources are tested available on http://*website_external_ip*:3000/

```
GET http://X.X.X.X:3000/js/app.4f600198.js 200 OK
```

**How should I write the Nginx configurations to allow correct loading of these resources from the NodeJS service on port 3000?** Any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your NodeJS service and not Nginx. The correct URL for the css file is `https://example.com/control/css/chunk-vendors.42e53ce6.css`, but your NodeJS service is missing off the `control` part.

Comment: Yes, I think your comment on point. The NodeJS is still handling requests from the base url not the "url/control" path.

Comment: There are 2 exactly duplicated questions. https://serverfault.com/questions/998021/gitlab-showing-404-while-running-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy-all-within-a-docker https://serverfault.com/questions/796930/nginx-is-giving-404-errors-on-all-but-the-html-pages